# How to log users actions in Laravel? How to listen to controllers methods?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, listen

I'd like to study users behaviors by recording in a specific table of the database any actions made by the users (user, timestamp, [controller and method names] or [url and request method]).

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224175/logging-user-actions-in-laravel) deals with a similar question but it seems to be listening to three methods ; I'd rather prefer a more global solution.

So, here is what I tried so far:

global.php

```
Event::listen('*', function(){
    $action = Event::firing();
    App::make('SpyController')->spy($action);
});
```

SpyController.php

```
class SpyController extends BaseController {
    public function spy($action){
        $spy = new Spy();
        $spy->name=$action;
        $spy->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $spy->save();
    }
}
```

Doing so, I get a timeout error. I guess that there are too many things to listen to, and I should better limit to a choice of controllers. However, I don't understand how to listen to specific controllers. The documentation presents an example with `auth.login`. If I got it right, this stands for `model.method`. Is it possible to listen to `controller.method`?

Answer (score 2):

Timeout error I thought because you have a controller LogController instead of SpyController

auth.login, auth.attempt, router.* are builti-in laravel src and fires with dispatcher.
So, if you need to make a listner for controllers you can create a middleware, which will fire an event with enything you want.
For example:
middleware registred name - spylogs.
Handle method(in middleware):

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $method = $request->method();
        Event::fire('some_name.'.$method);
        return $next($request);
    }
```

In controller:

```
$this->middleware('spylogs');
```

Wherever you want:

```
Event::listen('some_name.method_name', callback);
```

Comment: Oups, sorry, that was a typo. `Log` is a reserved word, and I can't use it as a model name. Therefore I replaced `log`by `spy` everywhere in order to be consistent, and I updated the question. If I listen to `router.before` which seems to be the first event, the script works fine. But listening to `*` makes it work too long. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks. I just checked the documentation to understand what a middleware was. Does this also exist for Laravel 4.2? I couldn't find it... Also, do I have to add some code to each method to monitor? I may have a hundred of them... Listening to every actions, and then filtering by class/controller name before registering would be ideal...